# Google Map API : Geometry Library "computeDistanceBetween" method billing?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google-maps Geometry Library,

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween
```

**It is not available in the pricing table anywhere**. How Google is charging money for the same. I need help for confirmation.

Is it coming from other libraries like places or distance-matrix?
As per new policy one need to compulsorily add GOOGLE_API_KEY and google charges accordingly.

As far as I searched the Geometry library is the individual one and it is a static method.

Answer (score 0):

**computeDistanceBetween** is just a static method.

Billing related details are provided in the below link,
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/usage-and-billing

More About Geometry Library,
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical.computeDistanceBetween